# Userena - Extending the Profile model further upto two different models

Tags: python, django

What i am trying to achieve is that i want to extend the profile model further to either teacher or student. In the signup form I added a choice field where user select whether he is teacher or student. Below is my model structure.

```
class Profile(UserenaLanguageBaseProfile):        
     """ Default profile """
     GENDER_CHOICES = (
             (1, _('Male')),
             (2, _('Female')),
         )

     user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='profile')

    gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('gender'),
                                              choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
                                              blank=True,
                                              null=True)

class Teacher(Profile):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('profile'),
                                related_name='teacher')

    home_address =  models.CharField(_('home_address'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    home_phone =  models.CharField(_('home_phone'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    cell_phone =  models.CharField(_('cell_phone'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    experience =  models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    summary =  models.TextField(_('summary'), max_length=500, blank=True)

class Student(Profile):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('profile'),
                                related_name='student')

    grade = models.CharField(_('grade'), max_length=50, blank=True)
```

I am overriding the signup save method as:

```
def save(self):
        new_user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save()
        new_user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        new_user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        new_user.save()

        if self.cleaned_data['teacher_or_student'] == 'teacher':
            teacher = Teacher(profile = new_user.get_profile())
            teacher.save()
        elif self.cleaned_data['teacher_or_student'] == 'student':
            student = Student(profile = new_user.get_profile())
            student.save()
        return new_user
```

When teacher.save() or student.save() method is called it raises an integrity error that "(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")" but i am not creating a new user instance here i am trying to assign the newly created profile_id to teacher or student model. I am doing in the wrong way?? what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says you can't create a `Student` or `Teacher` without `user` as you've defined it as a non nullable field.

Make sure you're passing your class the `new_user` you've defined..

```
# ...
new_user.save()

if self.cleaned_data['teacher_or_student'] == 'teacher':
    teacher = Teacher(profile = new_user.get_profile(), user=new_user)
    teacher.save()
elif self.cleaned_data['teacher_or_student'] == 'student':
    student = Student(profile = new_user.get_profile(), user=new_user)
    student.save()
```

Comment: i am so dumb. sometimes these small things gives you headache. Thanks a lot friend. +1

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but why do you subclass your models from Profile model (so you have a "user" field in it already), and right after you have a "profile" OneToOneField field for Profile model again?