# Multiple User Profile with Django Userena

Tags: django, django-users, django-profiles

I'm using userena 1.2 and Django 1.4. I'm trying to create multiple user profiles but I had no luck following many post found here on SO.

I've create 2 custom Models and a form like so:

```
class BaseProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    """ Default profile """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, verbose_name = _('user'), related_name='base_profile')

    @property # accessing a method as a property
    def is_seller(self):
        """Find out if this is a Seller user"""
        try:
            self.seller
            return True
        except Seller.DoesNotExist:
            return False

    def get_profile_type(self):
        """return the profile type model"""
        if self.is_seller:
            return self.seller
        else:
            return self.customer


class Seller(BaseProfile):
    company = models.CharField(_('Company'),max_length=100, null=True, blank=True,)


class Customer(BaseProfile):
    favourite_snack = models.CharField( _('favourite snack'), max_length=5 )
```

And overridden the Signup form:

```
class SignupFormExtra(SignupForm):
    # stuff in here
    def save(self):
        # stuff in here
```

Now the problem is inside the *save* method.
Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10820986/1191416) I've tried to implement a *custom manager* but I had no luck (I'm a django newbie). The important point that I understood is that the `Save` method shoud return a Django User, not a userena profile.

```
def save(self):
    user = super(SpamSignupForm,self).save()
    new_customer = Customer.objects.create_user()
    return new_user
```

Then I've tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8949176/1191416):

```
def save(self):
    new_user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save()
    new_user.save()
    customer = Customer(profile = new_user.get_profile(), user=new_user)
    customer.save()
    return new_user
```

The `get_profile()` method will always (I guess) returns the base profile defined in settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE.
Also it seems wrong to me that the author used a `profile` field in the *subprofile* as a OneToOne relation to the **Baseprofile** WHILE implementing a *multi-table inheritance*, why? It doesn't seem right to me.

```
class Customer(Baseprofile):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Baseprofile,
                            unique=True,
                            verbose_name=_('profile'),
                            related_name='student')
```

Yes, basically I've spent a full day trying to figure this out and I'm still lost.

Answer (score -2):

it is better to use django-registration. install and add it to `INSTALLED_APPS =(.....'registration',`

now create two user in

#### registration/models.py

```
.................

class Seller(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    companyname= models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Customer(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    favourite_snack = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

#### in registration/views.py

```
........
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from registration.models import Seller,Customer
from django.http import HttpResponse
def auth_login(request,utype):
    temp_login='registration/%slogin.html' %utype
    try:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']        
    except KeyError:
        return render(request,temp_login)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if utype=='seller':
        try:Seller.objects.get(user=user)
        except: return render(request,temp_login,{'errors':True})
    if utype=='customer':
        try:Customer.objects.get(user=user)
        except: return render(request,temp_login,{'errors':True})    
    if user.is_active:
        login(request,user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/'+request.GET['next'])#,render(request,'%s/home.html' %utype)
    return render(request,temp_login,{'errors':True})
```

#### edit registration/auth_urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^login/(employer|jobseeker)/$',
                           auth_login,name='auth_login'),
```

#### registration/backends/default/views.py

inside `class RegistrationView(BaseRegistrationView):`

inside `def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):` add

```
if self.args[0]=='e': usertype=Seller()
        else: usertype=Customer()        
        usertype.user=new_user
        usertype.save()
```

#### registration/backends/default/urls.py

add these line

```
url(r'^register/([ej])/$',
                           RegistrationView.as_view(),
                           name='registration_register'),
```

Comment: I actually wanted to use userena in order to use all its other features that would take time to rewrite by myself (user account creation and editing, mugshot, messaging, visibility of the account from other users). Any alternative to implement these mixing django-registration with other reusable apps?

Comment: actually these codes are not built in in django-registration. you have better not use django-registraion. try to impelement these codes like editing urls.py, views.py ..etc in userena

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do but I'm stuck in the phase of creating multiple profiles in userena.